# Bundling AWS v3 SDK with Webpack in an AWS Lambda w/ Serverless Framework?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, webpack, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have an AWS application, implemented as a single Lambda function, that I'm developing in Typescript with the Serverless framework. It consists of an API and a simple web UI in Express. The application will start an ECS task (which is what the API does) and the UI will poll ECS for the task status and display such to the user.

I'd like to use the v3 AWS SDK for this. Reading over the [docs for using the v3 SDK in the browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/browser-js-considerations.html), I see that I should download the individual clients I want to use with `npm` or `yarn`, then bundle them into the Javascript file for the UI with Webpack. Trouble is, I'm already using Webpack to translate Typescript into Javascript. How do I configure Webpack to translate and bundle the Typescript for the API into one file and the Javascript for the UI into another?

Answer (score 1):

in my team we decided to use not serverless framework. instead we are using cdk and lambda layers and aws-sdk v3 (typescript) for nodejs. with lambda layer I provide the node_modules folder and reference this layer in my own lambdas. But I also played around with webpack before, see the config files below. the structure in dist folder is needed to have easy reference in cdk. I think in your case you have only to change library target in webpack.config.js file and than it should work in browser also.

webpack.config.js

```
// webpack.config.js -> we´ve only one config for production/dev -> context: lambda (no minifiying etc. needed)
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: "node14", // needed to build proper nodejs14 code (without browser stuff)
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname, // to automatically find tsconfig.json
  entry: {
    callCreateLogs: './src/functions/callCreateLogs/index.ts',
    // TODO: add new functions here, maybe later here an additional script will do this for us (the key must match to the folder for right cdk reference)
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map', // to find errors (we use that also in productions for backend lambdas)
  output: {
    filename: '[name]/index.js', // generated file based on the entry key
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs', // important for aws lambda context
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(), // clean up dist folder before build
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
          transpileOnly: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "test"]
}
```

here a cdk snippet:

```
this.CreateLogLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'createLogLambda', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../../backend/dist/createLogs')), // hint: only directory which include the file (no filename here)
      handler: 'index.handler', // filename.methodname (without file extension),
      //role: createLogsLambdaExecutionRole
    });
```

Comment: I can't remember what project this was for, otherwise I'd try it out and let you know. :D